# Using Lambda for data processing - Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a docker image which has Entrypoint as processing.py. This script is taking data from /opt/ml/processing/input and after processing putting it /opt/ml/processing/output folder.

For processing the data I should put the file in /opt/ml/processing/input from s3 and then pick processed file from /opt/ml/processing/output into S3.

Following script in sagemaker is doing it properly:

```py
from sagemaker.processing import Processor, ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput 
import sagemaker

input_data = 's3://sagemaker-ap-south-1-057036842446/sagemaker/Data/Training/Churn_Modelling.csv' 
output_dir = 's3://sagemaker-ap-south-1-057036842446/sagemaker/Outputs/' 
image_uri = '057036842446.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/aws-docker-repo:latest' 
aws_role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

processor = Processor(image_uri= image_uri, role=aws_role, instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge")

processor.run(
    inputs=[
        ProcessingInput(
            source=input_data,
            destination='/opt/ml/processing/input'
        )
    ],
    outputs=[
        ProcessingOutput(
            source='/opt/ml/processing/output',
            destination=output_dir
        )
    ]
)
```

Could someone please guide how this can be executed with lambda function? It is not recognizing sagemaker package, second there is a challenge in placing file before the script execution and pick processed files.

I am trying codepipeline to automate this operation. However got no success on that.

Not sure how to put image from S3 into folders internally used by script

I need to know how S3 processing step which pick data from /opt/ml/processing/input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kick off a Processing Job from Lambda you can use boto3 to make the `CreateProcessingJob` API call:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_processing_job

I would suggest creating the Job as you have been doing using the SageMaker SDK. Once created, you can describe the Job using the `DescribeProcessingJob` API call:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.describe_processing_job

You can then use the information from the `DescribeProcessingJob` API call output to fill out the `CreateProcessingJob` in Lambda.